# Java Class not found when using DB2 library

Tags: java, db2

I've been trying to get my program to work but keep getting a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException message.

I am using Eclipse 2019 on Windows and have JDK 1.8 installed. When I run the program from Eclipse's Run menu, it works fine. But, after exporting the JAR and running from the CLI, it gives this exception. I am including the DB2 driver in the project as this program is planned to run on another computer.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        Connection connection = null;

        // Load the properties from the resource
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = WebsiteUpdater.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("database.properties");
            prop.load(inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Failed to load properties file from resources");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        // Connect to the database
        try {
            Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfex) {
            // THIS IS THE EXCEPTION THAT IS THROWN
            System.out.println("Problem in loading or registering IBM DB2 JDBC driver");
            cnfex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:db2://" + prop.getProperty("database.server") + ":" + prop.getProperty("database.port") + "/" + prop.getProperty("database.dbname"),
                    prop.getProperty("database.user"),
                    prop.getProperty("database.password"));
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            System.out.println("Failed to get connection");
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        // Close and exit
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to close connection");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Program completed");
    }
```

I created a folder called libs and put the files there.

[image: Project folders]

Then I added the class paths:

[image: Project class paths]

As I said, the program works from within Eclipse, but from the command prompt, I get:

```
Problem in loading or registering IBM DB2 JDBC driver
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at net.mydomain.MyApp.main(MyApp.java:50)
```

Comment: When running in the CLI, how have you set CLASSPATH, before starting your program?

Comment: CLASSPATH is not set

Comment: If you have not set CLASSPATH in the command-prompt (or system environment variables) to include the fully-qualified path to where the Db2-driver jar files are located then you will get this exception. This is a FAQ. You can set the CLASSPATH either in a script file before running your java app, or set it in the system (or user) environment variables of your MS-Windows product.

Comment: Yes, I know. Which is why I am including the db2jcc.jar in the project

Comment: Regardless, if CLASSPATH variable is incorrectly set (or not set) then you will get this exception. Trivial to prove!

Comment: Um, let's not get into the debate. Accepting for the moment, I copied the 2 jar's into the same folder as the compiled jar and set CLASSPATH=. and tried again. Got the same result.

Comment: Ah! If I export it as a runnable JAR, then everything works as expected. Now, why would that be?

Comment: Because when you make it into a runnable jar the other dependencies are included in the jar file (you can open it with e.g. winzip and look). Normally you just add other dependencies on the classpath when you run your application instead (as I explained in my answer). That makes it possible to reuse the dependencies and or replace them without having to recreate the jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cmd should look something like this:

```
java -cp json-simple-1.1.1.jar;db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar;db2jcc_license_cu.jar;db2jcc4.jar;<yourapplication.jar> net.mydomain.MyApp
```

Comment: As I said, I wanted to put the db2 driver within the jar so as to be able to run it on another computer.

Comment: Well, what you said was it runs in eclipse but not on CLI. So what I showed you was how to solve that. This is also how eclipse runs it.